# torify a c# application

Tags: server

I have this code that will communicate with a server to send a data, I want it to send the data through TOR .I heard it uses the SOCKS protocol, So how can I use my client app to communicate over TOR with my server.Here is my code that sends data over regular HTTP protocol

```
  public void sendKey()
    {
        string url="http://localhost:8731/savekey.aspx";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();            
        formData["clientpassword"] = encryptedPassword;
        byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(url,"POST",formData);
        webClient.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: It will help you - a [custom WebClient class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122369/use-webclient-with-socks-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a proxy in there somehow.

The classes you're using [don't support SOCKS proxying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13123733/2875107).

One way to get around this would be to [use Privoxy](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/1989/1730), then proxy using the appropriate port. The (simplified) pertinent code then becomes:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8118");
client.Proxy = wp;
```